# Is it possible to get the value (not key) in a literal object as a literal, not its type (such as string) via mapped type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

Below, I have a literal object {a:"a"}. I want to extract the value of the object as a literal "a", not its type string, so as to check if some other variables is "a" and not any other string.

However if I use mapped type I only get string, not "a".

Is there a way to get the value as a type?

```
const a = {a:"a"}
type trueIfLiteral<T extends string>= string extends T?false:true;

type key = keyof typeof a;
const t1 : trueIfLiteral<key> = true; // key is literal

type val = typeof a[key];
const t2 : trueIfLiteral<val> = false; // val is string
```

So the question is simply, how can I derive a type:

```
type valAsLiteral = "a"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to make the object slightly less confusing, let's call it `obj` with properties `key` and `val`:

```
const obj = { key: "val" };
```

A problem here is that the object is typed as `{ key: string }`. TypeScript has automatically widened the `'val'` from `'val'` to a string. If you want to prevent that widening, you can declare the object `as const`:

```
const obj = { key: "val" } as const;
```

This results in your code working, and

```
type val = typeof obj[key];
```

produces `'val'` (and `const t2 : trueIfLiteral<val> = false; // val is string` fails, because `val` is no longer a generic string, but only `val`)

To get the value in the emitted JS, not in TS, you can do

```
const val = Object.values(obj)[0];
```

producing `'val'`, typed as `'val'`, with no type widening.

Comment: Thanks! There's always amazing surprise in typescript typing! Powerful and fascinationg!